# UIImageView setImage not working?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a class in which i have two UIImageViews. After if control i am setting the image of these ImageView but it is not set.

I am calling the method from another class.

My code is as below,

```
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle,number,index,vstd,sold;

NSString *identifier;
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

  self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

  if (self != nil)
    {

     UIImageView * ecz = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
     ecz.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 87, 50);
     ecz.image = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"eczane_indicator"];
     [self addSubview:ecz];
     [ecz release];

     vstd = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 25, 22)];
     [self addSubview:vstd];
     [vstd release];

     sold = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 25, 22)];
     [self addSubview:sold];
     [sold release];
    }

  return self;

  }

-(void) visitOrderFlag : (NSString*)visitFlag withOrderFlag:(NSString*)orderFlag
{

 if([visitFlag isEqualToString:@"0"])
  {
   UIImage *visitedImage = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"pharm1"];
   [vstd setImage:visitedImage];
  }
 else
 {
  UIImage *visitedPressedImage = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"pharm2"];
  [vstd setImage:visitedPressedImage];
 }

 if([orderFlag isEqualToString:@"0"])
 {
  UIImage *orderedImage = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"pharm3"];
  [sold setImage:orderedImage];
 }
 else
 {
  UIImage *orderedPressedImage = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"pharm4"];
  [sold setImage:orderedPressedImage];
 }

}

@end
```

What am i missing?

Please show me a solution

Comment: [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"pharm1"] If it is empty, the image will not set.

Comment: instead cachedImage i am using UIImage imageNamed: but result is the same

Answer (score 2):

use this method and and add a observer in your view controller class to observe change in image object . When it notifies then you can put your image object into UIimageView.

```
-(UIImage *)thumbImage{

          __block UIImage *myImage;
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[Utility systemFilePath:imageURL_]]) {
            NSData *imageData =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[Utility systemFilePath:imageURL_]];
            if (imageData != nil) {
                dealImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            }
        }
        else{



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                //Load image in background
                NSData* imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: dealImageURL_]];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                    if(myImage){
                        NSString *filePathToSave = [Utility systemFilePath:imageURL_];
                        if (filePathToSave) {
                             [self willChangeValueForKey:@"profileImage"];
                             [imgData writeToFile:filePathToSave atomically:YES];
                             [self didChangeValueForKey:@"profileImage"];


                        }
                    }

                });
            });
        }

        return myImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 *ecz.image = [STCachedImage getCachedImage:@"eczane_indicator"];
```

This Method getchachedImage took time , and you are releasing the image view after that.

Comment: you can do one thing get your image in background thread and when image is completely downloaded then you can notify by delegate or notification and pass the image object to set in your image view.

Comment: the point is, when i use UIImage imageNamed: it is still the same, not set